# Multiple deleteRowsAtIndexPaths called at once

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, animation, cells

I have a upload all task where items are uploaded to AWS S3. Once the item has uploaded, it fires a NSNotification to the viewcontroller to animate the cell (a swish left effect) and then remove the cell from the table view:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("itemUploaded", object: nil, userInfo: ["item": item])
```

The table view data source is managed by a list of these objects and their status. In the notification observer, after the swish animation (showExpandingButton) I get the cell this item belongs to and set the status to be .Uploaded and this removes it from the tableView data source.

```
cell.showExpandingButton({ (completed) in
    self.removeCells(item)
})
```

RemoveCells() then deletes the cell from the table view. However, the issue I'm facing is that the notification can be fired at pretty much the same time, meaning the table view data source can update quicker than the function to remove the cells. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you using table view animations? If you don't have to, I think using reloadData is safe even with repeated calls. If you have to, you have to somehow coalesce the notification calls so deleting cells from the table view is only called once in a runloop loop. I think you can take a look at NSNotificationQueue to help in doing that.

Comment: If the view controllers are related to each other, do not use `NSNotification`. Use protocol / delegate or callback closure instead.

Comment: The upload manager is not a view controller so I think it needs to be a notification. The NSNotificationQueue looks interesting - will see if that is an option thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than removing cells completely, I animate the row height change, as to prevent the clash between data source and number of rows in the table view due to the delay of the animation. Whilst not a complete solution - it works for my current scenario.